# Can we send packets directly to MAC address?

Tags: tcp, udp

I have a setup where there are few (let say 5) network devices connected in a LAN
The MAC addresses of these devices are all known to me. The IP addresses of these devices can change.
 Is it possible to send packet to other devices addressing to their MAC address ? Is there any such API ?

Comment: any Platform...Linux preferably

Comment: Then [start here](http://aschauf.landshut.org/fh/linux/udp_vs_raw/ch01.html). (Or [here](http://aschauf.landshut.org/fh/linux/udp_vs_raw/ch01s03.html).)